# How to make the AppSource install link work on Mac?

Tags: excel, macos, office-js, office-store, appsource

The web store 'Open In Excel' button does not work for Mac users. Excel indicates that it is downloading some file but then nothing happens. I'm sure expected behavior is that the workbook should open and install the add-in to Excel. Here is a video showing this, on Excel v16.40 (latest version as of this writing):

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MqlZyqhYe9MfOzJN_sjpFwyPHOn4LuPD/view?usp=sharing

I became aware of this issue because some of our customers have contacted us, asking why the add-in wasn't working. Who knows how many potential customers we have lost because they simply thought the add-in wasn't supported on their system and moved on.

Is this a problem with our add-in code? Is anyone at Microsoft aware of this issue?

Comment: Hi Brian, this issue was recently identified and a fix is currently rolling out to impacted builds. 
FYI the best place to get support with your Office add-ins is via your Partner Center account or directly at https://aka.ms/marketplacepublishersupport

Comment: Thanks @OfficeStoreDeveloperComms. I did initially try to resolve this through the Partner Center, but after two months of getting passed between various support without anyone even attempting to reproduce the issue, I was told that the product was behaving as designed and I would have to pay $15K for a premier account to get further support. Overall, an incredibly frustrating experience.

Comment: Hi Brian, this is resolved in Office for Mac 16.42. 
I've passed on your feedback about your Partner Center support experience.